# `nuxt.js` alternative for vue3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I have a vue3 cli app, which needs to support SSR for SEO concerns.
I want to use pages and layouts features of nuxt.js, but currently it doesn't support vue3.

So what to do now..? is there any framework like nuxt.js but supports vue3..?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Update 8/8/2022

Nuxt 3.0.0-rc.6 is now available and supports Vue 3.  Beware that it is missing functionality from Nuxt 2, but I feel the switch is already quite worth it.

Check [this roadmap](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/community/roadmap/) to see various module statuses.

---

**[Old answer:]**

You can use the composition API in Nuxt with the Nuxt Composition API [module](https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/).  It's experimental and not a final release but it may serve your purposes.  From the docs:

> @nuxtjs/composition-api provides a way to use the Vue 3 Composition API in with Nuxt-specific features.

Of course you could also continue to use Vue 2 with Nuxt.

### More Info

About 1.5 months ago, the official Nuxt Twitter [mentioned](https://twitter.com/nuxt_js/status/1331690026296598530) posting a roadmap for Nuxt 3 soon

You can see a Nuxt 3 roadmap slideshow [here](https://nuxtjs.slides.com/atinux/state-of-nuxt-2020-november#/5/1/1).  Use the arrows in the slider to scroll it down.